# Why do I get "data type mismatch in criteria expression?"

Tags: ms-access

I am very new to access ( I usually use MySQLi with Navicat) and I need to convert 10 digit isbn numbers to 13 digit.  I have the following query that calls a function to do just this ( I did not create the function, but it works and I use it when performing other queries):

```
    SELECT ISBN1013([ISBN]) AS ISBN13, LastSoldDate AS LastSold, Id AS Sku, OnHand AS Quantity, Store 
FROM [Store Inventory]
WHERE (((ISBN1013([ISBN])) Like "##########?"));
```

When I attempt to run it, everything looks fine at first, then I get an error message that states:  Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression.  I have tried to look this up on Google and here, but I am not finding anything that explains this error.
Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: Here a samples of how the information starts and how it should end up looking.

```
 0448431351 -> should end up as 9780448431352
 0736425543 -> should be 9780736425544
```

Comment: Do you have null values in the column ISBN?

Comment: No, I do not, just 10 digit isbn that I need to convert to 13 digit's

Comment: If you remove the WHERE clause, do you still get the error message?

Comment: No, I do not.  I think I need it in there to sort out all of the information in there that is not at least 10 character long though.

Comment: Yes you likely do need a WHERE clause, but not one that throws an error.  What is the data type of your `ISBN` field and what is the data type of the value returned by `ISBN1013()`?  This might be clearer if you show us sample `ISBN` values, what happens for each of those values, and what should happen.

Comment: Also you said 10 character `ISBN` values, but your Like pattern (`"##########?"`) is 11 characters.  This is confusing.  To select rows which have 10 character `ISBN` values you could use: `WHERE Len(ISBN) = 10`

Comment: @HansUp - both data types are text.  I will edit the original post to show samples of what they start at and how they should end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unsure how well I understand the problem, but since you said the error goes away without that `WHERE` clause, let's try a different `WHERE`.

My assumptions:

1. You want the query to operate on rows where `ISBN` consists of 10 numeric characters.  And all your 10 character `ISBN` values include only digits.
2. The query should also operate on rows with 11 character `ISBN` values if they consist of 10 digits followed by a letter.

If those assumptions are correct, try a WHERE clause similar to this (untested) version.

```
WHERE
    Len(ISBN) = 10
    OR (
           Len(ISBN) = 11
           AND ISBN ALike "%[a-z]"
       )
```

Comment: The isbn should only be 10 digits, or 9 with a letter at the end.  I adjusted the new WHERE clause to this and it works perfectly!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good.  Looks like it would help me to learn a little more about ISBN values.  Meanwhile, glad my answer pointed you to something useful even though my assumptions were faulty.  :-)

Comment: I am sure it was more that my explanation was vague, not that your assumptions were faulty.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting an `NZ` function around the ISBN field:

```
SELECT NZ(ISBN1013([ISBN]),"") AS ISBN13
```

This converts any null values to empty strings.

If that doesn't work, try `CStr`:

```
SELECT CStr(ISBN1013([ISBN])) AS ISBN13
```

This converts any non-string values to strings. I know you've said you don't have any null values, but in my experience, it's one of those things which works even when you think that all the data matches the expected format.

Comment: Still getting the error message.  Could it be caused by soem of the values in the isbn field end with a letter instead of a number, like 123456789x?

Comment: That shouldn't be it, because the `Like` part expects a string, and a string is what you're giving it. I'm sorry, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're new to Access, so I thought I'd clarify on HansUps comment.  Can you look at the ISBN1013() function in the VBA module? The first line should be something like:

```
Function ISBN1013(ISBN as string) as string
```

Can you check that this line ends in 'string' and not something else?

Comment: Here is the first line:  Function ISBN1013(ByVal ISBN As String) As String